# How to set VLC volume with qdbus?

Tags: d-bus, vlc

Seems like this should be pretty simple.

I can see the volume this way:

```
#> qdbus org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Volume

0.600006103515625
```

I can try to set it in any of these ways, but the volume goes to zero:

```
#> qdbus org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Volume 0.5

#> qdbus org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Volume double:0.5

#> qdbus org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player Volume double:0.5

#> qdbus org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player Volume variant:double:0.5
```

I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never: After a little bit too much googling I stumbled over [this thread](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=135870), where some clever guy posted the not so obvious solution:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --session --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set string:org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player string:Volume variant:double:1.0
```